# Click to open folder within QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am currently using the Map Tip function to display an image when I hover over a point within the canvas. I would like to be able to click on the image to open its folder location. How can I modify the code below to include *href* and make the image clickable? I would prefer to avoid using the "Actions" function.

`%path%` = image path

`%folder%` = folder location

This is the working code I'm using to display the image. `<img src="file:///[%Path%]" width="500"/>`

I was trying to use *href* within the code and I was not successful. `<a href="file:///[%folder%]"<img scr="file:///[%path%]" width="500"></a>`

[image: Working Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have try the following code and it works :

```
<a href="file:///[%folder%]"><img src="file:///[%path%]"></a>
```

Are you sure of the names of your fields (especially the case)?

Answer (score 0):

You will need `.htaccess` file in the folder you have stored images.

1. Go to the folder and create a new text file.
2. Write `Options+Indexes` in the file.
3. Change the name of the text file to `.htaccess`.